# Range Input Element: Is there a way to Dynamically Change the Min Value?

Tags: jquery, html, range

I am working on a page using only html5 and jquery, and I have a range input as follows:

```
<input id="mySlider" type="range" class="test" min="2" max="32" step="2" value="10" />
```

Is there any way to dynamically alter the min of this input?  I've tried referencing / setting by using getElementByID and trying to access the min attribute (the same way you could do for .value), but this doesn't appear to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully changed the value in many ways, including:

```
document.getElementById('mySlider').min = 5; // Example: min value of 5
$('#mySlider').prop('min', 5);               //jQuery method
```

Make sure that you have spelled `document.getElementById` correctly, using a lowercase `d`.

Go try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8W7FF/

Comment: +1 for using the correct method `.prop` over the acceptable but oh so wrong and confusing `.attr`

Comment: Hmm; it doesn't work for me: in my code I have: alert(document.getElementById('mySlider').value);
alert(document.getElementById('mySlider').min);     and the first alert is 10 and the second is undefined?

Comment: @user201926 Use the fiddle. Does it produce the right results? If yes, the issue is caused by something else at your code. What browser are you using?

Comment: I don't see a slider on the fiddle?

Comment: **Go upgrade your browser.** `input[type=range]` is a **HTML5** feature, which is only supported by the **newest** browsers. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: I'm up to date: Firefox 7.0.1.  I see the sliders on the page I'm currently working on, but not in this fiddle project for some reason.  I just see a text box with the number 10

Comment: Oh wait... this isn't native to firefox i think?  I have some code to show a jquery slider if range element is unavailable...hmm

Comment: At the fiddle, I see a slider in Chromium 14. At Firefox 7.0.1, however, I don't see a slider. According to this [compability table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input#AutoCompatibilityTable), Firefox doesn't seem to support a slider yet. I guess that your page is implementing a slider script, to add a slider feature to the `input[type=range]`.

Comment: Yeah; that's it.  Well, you answered the stated question so I guess we can call this a case closed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mySlider").attr("min",12);
```

should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/SNuK6/

Answer (score 0):

How about accessing the attribute directly?

```
$("#mySlider").attr("min", 4);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attr/